# Calling TFS query in another TFS Query

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to call one TFS Query in another TFS Query & further filter data?

Working in TFS 2013.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t the feature of creating new queries in TFS based on the result of another query presently.

Kindly take a look at this similar question:[Queries based on the elements of other queries?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27c33990-b234-4100-a06a-cb1e610ca99b/queries-based-on-the-elements-of-other-queries?forum=tfsworkitemtracking)

> The only way to do this is using TFS API from a language like C#,
>   where you can run a query, then use that query to do another query
>   based on its results.
>
> There are some articles about TFS Query API that may benefit you:
>
> - [Fetch work items with queries programmatically in Azure DevOps    Services/TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/work-item-quickstart?view=azure-devops)
> - [TFS 2010 SDK: Get Projects, Iterations, Area Path, Queries and Work    Items Programmatically](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx)

Besides, you could also [**submit a feature request**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/Azure+DevOps.html), our product team is listening to user voice there. They will kindly review any suggestion.