# Is it possible to Reuse a Query?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is it possible to reuse a query like JIRA does it? For example:

Query (pseudocode):

```
     'Work Item Type' ... equals    ... 'Bug'
AND  'Area Path'      ... not under ... 'Demo'
```

save this as a shared query '123'

All my future queries that need the same filters would just say

```
    'Query' ... equals ... '123' (or similar: queryId and such)
AND 'State' ... equals ... 'Closed'
```

... So It would give me all 'closed' 'Bugs', not under 'Demo'. I hope I made the idea clear... Maybe there is an extension that provides similar functionality? thanks!

Comment: Three years later... maybe by now there's an actual answer to OP's qestion on how to reuse a query which can be edited at a single source of truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All my future queries that need the same filters

If I understand correctly, you want a template query and have future queries would be based on this template query.

This would need no extension, just open your shared query '123' and add more conditions then click the `Save as...` above, input a name and choose a folder then click `OK` to save the new query.

[image]

Comment: what if a 'template' query needs to be changed? I'd need to filter out not only 'Demo', but also a 'Sandbox' Area Paths. Does it mean I will have to go through all 'forked' queries and update them? thank you

Comment: Yes, you have a good point and i apologize for missing this situation. But, unfortunately there's no such a function or [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=query&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Boards&sortBy=Relevance) can meet the requirement at current time. However, here's a work around you can use a 3rd party api which please refer to [Calling TFS query in another TFS Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59024349/12722389).

Comment: yes, thank you... => something to add to the backlog, I guess :) - this is an extremely powerful concept

Answer (score 1):

The [Work Item Query Editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) will help you. You can import and export entire queries or snippets to quickly reuse a set of filters. Syntax reference [for WIQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops)

I would also recommend the [Open in Excel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=blueprint.vsts-open-work-items-in-excel) extension if you are going to be doing a bunch of bulk edits.